# Django Max Function not returning Maximum Value

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need the maximum value of a particular field in my database, increment it by 1 and that becomes my new order number.

The way I do that is:

```
def generate_order_number(self):
    q_number = Order.objects.all().aggregate(Max('number'))['number__max']
    if q_number:
        q_number += 1
    else:
        q_number = 1

    return q_number
```

This code works perfectly fine until order number 10. However, when order number 11 is attempted, the `aggregate` query returns max value as 9 and thus, the function returns 10 as the new order number - which fails the entire process (number is `unique` in the database).

Why would this be happening?

I am using Django/PostgreSQL combination. My database entry for `number` is:

```
number = models.BigIntegerField(
    _("Quotation number"), db_index=True, unique=True)
```

Also, when I try to directly manipulate the database for order number, the error I get is:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/order/order/21/
operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ..._order" WHERE ("order_order"."number" = 11 AND N...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the ID of the order as its order number? Then it will always be unique.

Comment: ^ And it will auto-increment

Comment: @jonrsharpe I may decide, later down the line, to reuse order numbers - for example, after 500000, I may delete the first 100000 and reuse those order numbers.
Or I may want the ability to search by order numbers. Which is why I decided to use a separate field.

Comment: *"Or I may want the ability to search by order numbers."* - you can search by ID. Also, note that your current method of finding the biggest so far and adding one doesn't let you delete and reuse the first 100,000 numbers anyway.

Comment: Yes, but that leaves me with a flexibility to modify code and do that (reuse). I cannot play with ids.

Comment: You really appear to be looking for sequences, Postgres can handle this internally for you and will be much more reliable. If you really want to you could even reset the sequence and re-use the numbers in the beginning.

Comment: @Wolph that sounds exactly like what I need to do. Could you point me in the right direction as to how do I go about this?

Comment: @GauravWadhwani have you tried searching for *"postgres sequences"*?

Comment: A `serial` column (which is the default for the primary key used by Django) automatically generates a sequence for you and handles it all internally. To reset the sequence (for the first 100,000) you can just use the `setval()` method.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: Thanks @Wolph . Please make this your answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) datatype internally creates both a `smallint`/`int`/`bigint` column and a sequence. Effectively making it equivalent to a normal int column with a default set to some sequence.

For example, this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

Internally results in this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

This is where your question comes in, while a plain [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createsequence.html) just adds a simple sequence that increments by one and will never go down. Using [`setval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html) you can reset the sequence current value to reuse old numbers.

Do note that this can result in duplicate key constraints since the primary key will still be unique so if you do get duplicate key constraints, simply reset the sequence to a range that isn't in use yet (`SELECT MAX(colname)+1 FROM tablename` should give you a correct startpoint).